# Arrange random number of image in a div and fill up all the space

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Recently i need to build a website but i have some problem with arrange image in a div with responsive.

I have random number of photo which is from minimum 1 to maximum 7. Then i need to display this number of photo in a div and make sure all the photo will fill up all the space in that div. Is that any possible way to do so? Thanks.

[image]

Is there possible to make the number of image base on our design?
for example when only 1 image to display, will make it full size, if got 6 image, will display in 6 image pattern. Below are all example of output with number of image.
[image]

Comment: Provide some code please. Also you can try to set the css of each image to `display:block; width:100%; height:100%`

Comment: Keep an array of length whatever you want and it will contain position of elements. Shuffle the array and place the elements as per the position.

Comment: If you want a dynamic number of images to display in a row then the easiest solution would be Flexbox.

Answer (score 1):

Note: You can use masonry as a jquery plugin [i see that you already tag jquery in your question] or you can initialize with pure vanilla code.

You can use masonry [ http://masonry.desandro.com/ ].

Here is an example for an image gallery: http://desandro.github.io/masonry/demos/images.html

And here is another example of that [ http://demos.creative-punch.net/masonry-gallery/ ].

Basically all you need to do is to have a container and some items in there and to hook masonry to that container.

```
<div id="container">
    <!-- This will make sure our size stays right when using Masonry -->
    <div class="grid-sizer"></div>

    <!-- This is what Masonry will tile for you -->
    <div class="item">

        <!-- An image, of course! -->
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/650/450" class="image">

        <!-- This is the overlay for the hover -->
        <a class="overlay" href="#">
            <h3 class="title">Some title</h3>
            <div class="description">
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br>
                    consectetur adipisicing elit.
                </p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    ...
```

Then hook masonry:

```
    $(window).load( function() {

    $('#container').masonry({
        "itemSelector": ".item",
        "columnWidth": ".grid-sizer",
    });

});
```

And then style that if you need anything more.

Reference: http://creative-punch.net/2014/01/full-screen-image-gallery-using-css-masonry/